# jQuery set value of radio input

Tags: jquery, input, radio-button

Does anyone know how to check a radio input with jQuery?

I was thinking val() would work but apparently it only sets the value on text inputs.

```
 $('[name="radio_group"]').val('my_selected_value');
```

Nothing happens if I do that

Comment: how you know nothing is happening?

Comment: because I don't see the radio input getting checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
jQuery("#radio_1").attr('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the selected value into the selector, and set the `checked` property.

```js
 $('[name="radio_group"][value="3"]').prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="radio_group" value="1">1<br/>
<input type="radio" name="radio_group" value="2">2<br/>
<input type="radio" name="radio_group" value="3">3<br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

$('[name="radio_group"]').prop('checked',true);

This assumes that there is only one item with name ='radio_group'.

Comment: Making assumptions about code you haven't been shown isn't a great thing to do, especially when you consider that the main function of radio inputs is achieved by multiple inputs having the same name.

Comment: @winterblood fair enough.